# Unable to start mySQL server windows 8

Tags: database, windows-8, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have installed MySQL server about 1 year ago and I forgot the password. I am not sure if it was root or not too. Now I am in need of MySQL server but couldn't make it. When I open workbench and start server it says. "Assuming server is on" but nothing happens. I
tried to chance the password by using init file, after this also it gives me the same problem. 
I also tried to start the server using mysqld cmd command but I am unable to start. I do not t understand what the problem is. Please help me I am not much used to MySQL so tell me if there is any basic problem too.

Here is the error file:

```
    2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-10 13:14:36 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-08-10 13:14:40 10216 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 1625977
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [ERROR] C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: unknown variable 'explicit_defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Binlog end
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-08-10 13:14:41 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-08-10 13:14:43 10216 [Note] C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

my-default.ini file:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF YOU NEED ANY MORE INFO

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the MySQL manual on this topic

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I already tried resetting it using the process given but it didn't work.

Comment: What error messages do you get when using the MySQL command line?

Comment: It asks me for password and when I enter the password I have changed it says unable to connect access denied